# Find all $z$ such that $\frac{z}{13}=s(z)$ where $s(z)$ is the digit sum of $z$

Tags: number-theory

I found this olympiad question:

> Find all $z$ such that $\frac{z}{13}=s(z)$ where $s(z)$ is the digit sum of $z$.

With a little programming I only found $117, 156, 195$ for $z<10^9$ and I think these are the only ones. The number $z$ can be written uniquely as $z=100 a+10 b+c$ with an integer $a \geq 0$ and digits $b, c \in\{0,1,2, \ldots, 9\}$, where we allow leading zeros in the decimal representation. Then $s(z)=s(a)+b+c$, so $z=13 \cdot s(z)$ is equivalent to
$
100 a+10 b+c=13 \cdot(s(a)+b+c)
$
and therefore
$
100 a-13 \cdot s(a)=3 b+12 c .
$
But I do not know if this leads somewhere. Any hints on how to continue or solve this problem?

Comment: The sum of digits is like a logarithm, so $\frac z{13}$ grows much faster than $s(z)$.  You should be able to assume a number of digits for $z$, find the maximum that $s(z)$ can be, and show the equation cannot be satisfied.  You can find an upper limit on $z$ that is smaller than $10^9$ and you are done.

Comment: A question of mine concerned the topic of how fast the digit sum rises and indeed, $s(a)\leq 9(\lfloor \log_{10}a\rfloor+1)$.

Comment: For any $z$, $s(z) \equiv z \pmod 9$. So, it may help to solve the modular equation $13x \equiv x \pmod 9$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1:

> Use the fact that $a \geq s(a)$ for all $a\in\mathbb{N}$.

Hint 2:

> Because of $a \geq s(a)$, the left-hand side $100a-13s(a)$ is at least equal to $87 a$. The right-hand side is at most equal to $3 \cdot 9+12 \cdot 9=135$, so it follows $87 a \leq 135$ and hence $a \leq 1$.

Hint 3:

> Case 1: $a=0$. Then because of your last equation, also $b=c=0$ and thus $z=0$. But this case is excluded. Case 2: $a=1$. In this case your last equation becomes $b+4 c=29$ after division by $3$. So $b\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, which leaves only the following possibilities: $$(b,c)\in\{(1,7),(5,6),(9,5)\}.$$ All three provide solutions to the problem, as the sample for $z \in\{117,156,195\}$ shows.